# Meteor with Parse - Running on Android Device - Parse is not defined

Tags: javascript, android, meteor, parse-platform

I'm using Meteor with Parse as my backend. When running as a web app, it is working fine. However, upon running the app on my android phone with `meteor run android-device`, its showing this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Parse is not defined

I have this `<script src="//www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.6.14.min.js"></script>` included in the `<head>` of the main html file as well as `Parse.initialize(.., .., ..)` on all .js files which requires/uses Parse.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding this line of code:

```
App.accessRule('*');
```

to mobile-config.js source file